# html2canvas adding "border" in divs with linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I have an issue with importing a div as an image with html2canvas.

I'm trying to download this div :
[image]

As an image and I'm getting this result :

[image]

And I don't know why, there is some kind of "border" that appears around the div that containt the linear-gradient, am I missing a property, or it is just a bug ?

*Note: This things don't happends when I remove the linear-gradient !*